# PostgreSQL: Getting sum of values of similar ids distinctly

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct

I have following relation in my database,

```
     id    |   month    | balance |
-----------+------------+---------+
 0009gmail | 2016-01-01 |    2000 |
 0009gmail | 2016-02-01 |    3500 |
 0009gmail | 2016-03-01 |     800 |
 0009gmail | 2016-04-01 |    1400 |
 0009gmail | 2016-05-01 |    -500 |
```

Problem is, I want sum of balance of distinct id with having date less than a specified date,

I am using this query for such:

```
select distinct(id),sum(balance) from payment group by id,month having month<'2016-06-22';
```

but it is giving this result,

```
       id    |   sum 
-------------+---------
   0009gmail |    2000
   0009gmail |     800
   0009gmail |    1400
   0009gmail |    3500
   0009gmail |    -500
```

I think I am getting this result because of putting month in group by clause, but removing same gives an error that month has to be in either group by of an aggregation function, i want this output,

```
     id    |   sum 
 ----------+---------
 0009gmail |    7200
```

please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple aggregation by `id`:

```
SELECT id, SUM(balance) AS balance
FROM payment 
WHERE month<'2016-06-22'
GROUP BY id;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/426473)**</kbd>

[image]

<sup>Image from: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20724.all-at-once-operations-in-t-sql.aspx</sup>

1. Get rows from `payement` table
2. Filter only those which satisfy `month<'2016-06-22'`
3. `GROUP BY` id
4. (`HAVING`) No needed

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `where` clause:

```
select id, sum(balance)
from payment
where month < '2016-06-22'
group by id;
```

I find the confusion amusing.  Most people try to put `having` logic in the `where` clause (aggregation functions are not permitted in `where` clauses).  It is quite rare to see the mistake in the other direction.

Also note that `select distinct` is almost never appropriate in an aggregation query.

Comment: If there is another entry with id 0009hotmail...?

Comment: So group by is grouping all the individual ids, right...?

Comment: `group by` produces a single row for each combination of keys in the `group by` clause, with the summaries as calculated in the `select`.